# Run Spark locally, addJar from sbt?

Tags: apache-spark, sbt

I have setup Spark 1.6 in a VM (using the gettyimages [Docker image](https://github.com/gettyimages/docker-spark)) to which I would like to connect to.

My Spark application uses Cassandra and if I run it with `setMaster("local[2]")`, it will run perfectly fine. However, if I choose `setMaster(spark://localhost:7077)` (localhost being here the 'address' of my Spark master), it will crash with a

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data
```

exception. I found on [github](https://github.com/tuplejump/calliope-release/issues/6) someone with a similar problem and the suggestion was to add the necessary library jars using `addJar(...)` to the SparkContext.

Currently, I use sbt and I do

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.6.0-M1"
)
```

for instance, for adding the Spark Cassandra connector to the context. However, when using sbt the jar files are not really in my repository. On the other hand,  `addJar(...)` wants the path to the jar file.

What is the best approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the documentation on **[Advanced Dependency Management](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management)**. Basically, you use the `--packages` command-line option for `spark-submit` and it does what you want

Comment: I can't follow, sorry. I don't do any explicit spark-submit, but I start the application where I create a `new SparkConf()` and set the master. Is what I am doing totally wrong?

Comment: Maybe -- try using `spark-submit` instead. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! I will now try to use `sbt-spark-submit` to run it from sbt.